# Wordpress enqueue script page conditional

Tags: javascript, wordpress, conditional-statements

Trying to load a few enqueue'd jQuery scripts based on certain template files but not getting them to load (calling this from functions.php):

```
function load_doc_scripts() {
    if (is_page_template('page-doc-new.php') || is_page_template('page-docs-main.php')) {
        wp_register_script(  'shadowbox', 
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/js/shadowbox.js', 
            array('jquery'), 
            '1.2' );

        wp_register_script(  'prettycode', 
            'https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js?skin=desert', 
            array('jquery'), 
            '1.2' );

        wp_enqueue_script('shadowbox');
        wp_enqueue_script('prettycode');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_doc_scripts');
```

Comment: Is this a child theme? Did you check the browser console for loading errors?

Comment: You're script is correct. Works for me. Look out if you have any conflicts with other scripts in functions.php. Try the function in a clean functions.php. Also make sure you're on a page template that uses page-doc-new.php.

Comment: ah, that was it. was calling the wrong file name, my bad.. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. Do your templates reside within a subfolder of the main theme folder?

Note: if the file is in a subdirectory you must include this as well. Meaning that this should be the filepath in relation to your theme as well as the filename, for example page-templates/about.php.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Is_a_Page_Template